# Spring @requestmapping with regex

Tags: java, regex, spring

I'm trying to have a regex in the request mapping but it seems that the server doesn't see the mapping:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/index/{postPath:^(?:mock_test[1-5]|reviewer_test(?:[145]|3[.][12]))$}", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String evaluateExam( @PathVariable
String postPath, @ModelAttribute( "wrapper" )
QuestionnaireBeanWrapper wrapper, HttpServletRequest request )
{
    //evaluateExam( wrapper, "Reviewer V" );
    EvaluationUnit evaluationUnit = new EvaluationUnit();
    try
    {
        List<String> answersList = new QuestionnaireDAO().getAnswerList( "Reviewer V" );
        StudentBean studentBean = evaluationUnit.executeEvaluation( wrapper, answersList );
        System.out.println( studentBean.getKnowledgeLevel() );
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        // no logger yet
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:../index/mock.do";
}
```

my form URL:

```
<form:form id="reading-form" action="../index/reviewer_test5.do" method="POST" modelAttribute="wrapper">
...
</form:form>
```

I tested the regex [here](http://regexr.com?37dui) and it is perfectly fine.

And about the `.do` suffix of my URLs it is define at my servlet configuration and I'm sure it is working because I've been using it for a month now.

Also if this also relevant my `get` mapping is also the same url as the post:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/index/reviewer_test5", method = RequestMethod.GET )
```

Comment: You make your life so difficult.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if I don't use regex I will have to write 10 controller with same logic inside. Do you have any suggestion to my case?

Comment: Maybe. Can you tell us what you mean by _it seems that the server doesn't see the mapping_? At startup, what do the logs say Spring registered as mappings?

Comment: It says post method is not supported. So I concluded that it doesn't see the mapping.